# Deploying New Relic on Heroku Cedar (PHP)

Tags: php, heroku, newrelic

Has anyone succesfully deployed the New Relic addon to a PHP app running on Heroku Cedar stack? I'm running a fairly high traffic Facebook app on a few dynos and can't get it to work.

The best info I can find details a Python deployment: http://newrelic.com/docs/python/python-agent-and-heroku

Thanks!

Comment: Contacted the relevant support channels yet? http://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/support and http://newrelic.com/support

Comment: Yes, their response just pointed me to the New Relic PHP documentation, nothing specific to Heroku. I've succesfully used New Relic for traditional PHP applications but just can't find anything on Heroku. http://newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Heroku has just recently rolled out support for PHP with Cedar and we at New Relic don't know anything more than you do.  We'll be talking with Heroku ASAP to get some docs developed which will certainly be on  ([New Relic's knowledge base](http://newrelic.com/docs)), and I'll report back here as well.

Edited to add:

Sorry for the long delay in me checking back in.  Unfortunately this is still not possible in a well-supported way, reason being that our php agent requires a standalone daemon to be running in addition to the dyno that is serving your content.  While you can find terrible hacks to get you into the space where you could fire up the daemon temporarily, it's not sustainable and won't port to the next dyno that spins up.  This means that we can't support you running the agent in this environment.

Edited to add:

As @aaron-heusser mentioned, support is finally official as of a month or so ago:  https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

Note: I work at New Relic.

Comment: I'm very interested in this as well.

Comment: +1. The Cedar stack is now very well supported and documented by Heroku.

Comment: Looks like it might be possible with a "Custom Build Pack" http://blog.iphoting.com/blog/2012/05/24/running-php-on-heroku/

Comment: +1 I'd like to see this supported, ideally automatically through the Heroku Addon, and not needing a custom build pack.

Comment: @fool - Is this still accurate, in Nov '13? I'd like to use the New Relic platform for monitoring PHP on Heroku if possible to do in a clean way.

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2014, New Relic PHP **does** support running on Heroku using the [official Heroku PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php).

See:

[New Relic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/installation/php-agent-heroku)

[Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#php-configuration)