# Getting New Relic Running for PHP on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, newrelic

So I've seen New Relic's guide here at https://newrelic.com/docs/php/new-relic-for-php

I ran heroku run /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon restart and it shows:

```
    Running `/etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon restart` attached to terminal... up, run.1
    bash: /etc/init.d/newrelic-daemon: No such file or directory
```

So it looks like the proxy daemon was not installed by installing the New Relic add-on.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contacted New Relic about this. Looks like it's currently not possible to run on Heroku.

Comment: NOTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092070/deploying-new-relic-on-heroku-cedar-php