# Setting up new relic on Heroku PHP

Tags: php, heroku, newrelic

I have a PHP app on Heroku that keeps giving an Application Error randomly, and the logs don't say anything at all. I can't be sure but it seems that the error comes when 6-8 concurrent users hit the app. To figure this out, I thought of installing the New Relic Add On, and I have been trying to follow the document here - https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/343400/applications/setup.

Please excuse my limited knowledge, but it seems that the instructions given here are supposed to be run on an actual server ? How can I run them for my Heroku server ? I use a windows machine. I have installed wget for windows, but then apt, deb ?

There are other discussions about this where people have mentioned that new relic is not supported on Heroku, but those are at least an year old. And Heroku is providing New Relic as an Add On.

Can anyone please help...

Comment: Duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092070/deploying-new-relic-on-heroku-cedar-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Relic does not officially support our PHP agent on Heroku.  Here's the current list of supported languages:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#supported-languages-and-frameworks

The setup requires the installation of a PHP extension and a local proxy daemon, which tends to require a bit more access to the app server.  If you have any tips, please share them here -- just keep in mind that we cannot support it.

Answer (score 3):

As of September 2014, New Relic PHP **does** support running on Heroku using the [official Heroku PHP buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php).

See:

[New Relic documentation](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/installation/php-agent-heroku)

[Heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/newrelic#php-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

I can't really give you an answer on this because we are currently in testing phase so we don't have concurrent users yet.

If you are using the official php buildpack from Heroku (if you've never heard of a buildpack you probably are) it's probably best that you ask their support as it might be a bug on their side. If you're using your own buildpack you can find an example of a working Heroku/PHP/Newrelic buildpack here:

> https://github.com/iphoting/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler

We haven't experienced the same problem with the above buildpack.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using the official php buildpack. I needed help with installing new relic. So I will have to have my own buildpack to achieve it ? There is no direct way of installing ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, PHP on Heroku is unsupported by New Relic.  See this SO question for more: [Deploying New Relic on Heroku Cedar (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092070/deploying-new-relic-on-heroku-cedar-php)

Comment: thanks, I did see that question earlier. But since the answer was 2 years old, I asked again - in case anything has changed. Especially because Heroku is now officially offering New Relic as an Add On.